# How do I instantiate a Prefab with a random name in Unity?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine

So I am working on a Building System in Unity everything was working just well until I addet the part where you can delete Objects with L because it deletes every Object with the same Name. I know that I need to Instantiate the Prefab with a random Name but I couldnt manage to do this.
I think another option is to identify the Object to delete in another way than just the name but I cant manage to do that. Here is my Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;

public class building : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Building;
    public GameObject BuildingPrefab;
    public GameObject FoundObject;
    public string RaycastReturn;

    bool BuildingModeOn;
    RaycastHit hit;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
      if(BuildingModeOn)
        {
            Building.SetActive(true);
            if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.transform.position, Camera.main.transform.forward, out hit, 20))
            {
                Building.transform.position = hit.point;
                RaycastReturn = hit.collider.gameObject.name;
                FoundObject = GameObject.Find(RaycastReturn);
                if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "ground" || hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "buildi")
                {
                    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
                    {
                        Instantiate(BuildingPrefab, hit.point, Building.transform.rotation);
                    }
                }

            }

        }
        else
        {
            Building.SetActive(false);
        }
      if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
        {
            BuildingModeOn = true;

        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))
        {
            BuildingModeOn = false;

        }
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {
            Building.transform.Rotate(Building.transform.rotation.x, 90f, Building.transform.rotation.z);
            BuildingPrefab.transform.Rotate(Building.transform.rotation.x, 90f, Building.transform.rotation.z);
        }

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.L))
        {
            if(Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.transform.position, Camera.main.transform.forward, out hit, 20))
            {
                RaycastReturn = hit.collider.gameObject.name;
                FoundObject = GameObject.Find(RaycastReturn);
                if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "buildi")
                {
                    Destroy(FoundObject);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I dont know what to do. Please help! thank you.

Comment: after you instantiate it, change the name

Answer (score 1):

I think it's happening because the name of all the objects you instantiated is same (as you stated). So, change the name of the object as soon as you instantiate it. First of all, define a variable like - `var temp`
Then, add `using.LINQ;` in the top and edit the code as follows:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
{
    temp = Instantiate(BuildingPrefab, hit.point, Building.transform.rotation);
    temp.name = randomName()
}

public static string randomName()
{
    const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
    .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
}
```